# Camera record review and upload android web view

Tags: android, ruby, camera, native, ruboto

Researching if it is possible to create a web app with jruby and ruboto that has access to android camera where user can record, review, and upload clip to server as either a native app or web app.

Not much documentation for this type of functionality.

Would like to prototype a demo using ruby since syntax is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

There are several Ruboto tutorials that should help you:

https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/wiki/Tutorials-and-examples

Use camera:

- https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Making-a-spycam

Post results:

- https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/wiki/Tutorial%3A-get-current-gps-position

The last uses the HTTP GET protocol, but switching to POST is trivial.

The server side is a regular JRuby web app using Sinatra, Rails, etc.

If you ned more help, file a ticket at https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/issues